# Spring security Kerberos was discontinued?

Tags: java, spring-security, single-sign-on, windows-authentication, spring-security-kerberos

I need to implement SSO (Windows authentication) with Java in an Web App. I already use Spring Security and i found an extension named Kerberos, but this extension appears to be discontinued.

The extension Kerberos for spring security was discontinued?

If it is, what alternatives are you using for SSO (Windows authentication) with Java?

[]'s

Comment: Why do you think it was discontinued? AFAIK only *spring-security-ntlm* was dropped. The only problem with [*spring-security-kerberos*](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/) is that it does not have official stable release yet (it's true that it is in this state for a few years now).

Comment: I suggest you to register at Spring Jira and vote for this issue - https://jira.spring.io/browse/SES-143 . I just did :).

Comment: Now, in 2022 it seems like this eventually happened. Documentation is so old and relies on deprecated Spring components.